# InfluxDB Copy data from one series to another

Tags: sql, influxdb

I've setup a home automation system which logs data into influxdb. I've two measuraments taken from two variables concerning the same sensor. I would like to remove the old table and migrate old data from the old table to the new. Old table 'entity_id=node21_child04', new one 'entity_id=node21samsung_21_4'.
I've following data entries in an influxdb database:

```
> show series;
key
---
C,domain=sensor,entity_id=node21_child04
°C,domain=sensor,entity_id=node21samsung_21_4
```

Looking on the content, extracting some data, I get those results:
Old table:

```
> SELECT * FROM "autogen"."°C" WHERE ("entity_id" = 'node21samsung_21_4') AND time >= now() - 10m;
name: °C
time                V_TEMP battery_level child_id description description_str          device_str domain entity_id          friendly_name friendly_name_str  heartbeat icon_str        node_id value
----                ------ ------------- -------- ----------- ---------------          ---------- ------ ---------          ------------- -----------------  --------- --------        ------- -----
1547484922088189952 9.3    0             4        11          Temperatura NORD (DHT11) mqtt       sensor node21samsung_21_4 21214         node21Samsung 21 4 0         mdi:thermometer 21      9.3
1547485042146836992 9.4    0             4        11          Temperatura NORD (DHT11) mqtt       sensor node21samsung_21_4 21214         node21Samsung 21 4 0         mdi:thermometer 21      9.4
1547485162424854016 9      0             4        11          Temperatura NORD (DHT11) mqtt       sensor node21samsung_21_4 21214         node21Samsung 21 4 0         mdi:thermometer 21      9
1547485282887762176 8.7    0             4        11          Temperatura NORD (DHT11) mqtt       sensor node21samsung_21_4 21214         node21Samsung 21 4 0         mdi:thermometer 21      8.7
```

New table:

```
> SELECT * FROM "autogen"."°C" WHERE ("entity_id" = 'node21samsung_21_4') AND time >= now() - 10m;
name: °C
time                V_TEMP battery_level child_id description description_str          device_str domain entity_id          friendly_name friendly_name_str  heartbeat icon_str        node_id value
----                ------ ------------- -------- ----------- ---------------          ---------- ------ ---------          ------------- -----------------  --------- --------        ------- -----
1547484922088189952 9.3    0             4        11          Temperatura NORD (DHT11) mqtt       sensor node21samsung_21_4 21214         node21Samsung 21 4 0         mdi:thermometer 21      9.3
1547485042146836992 9.4    0             4        11          Temperatura NORD (DHT11) mqtt       sensor node21samsung_21_4 21214         node21Samsung 21 4 0         mdi:thermometer 21      9.4
1547485162424854016 9      0             4        11          Temperatura NORD (DHT11) mqtt       sensor node21samsung_21_4 21214         node21Samsung 21 4 0         mdi:thermometer 21      9
1547485282887762176 8.7    0             4        11          Temperatura NORD (DHT11) mqtt       sensor node21samsung_21_4 21214         node21Samsung 21 4 0         mdi:thermometer 21      8.7
```

I would like to migrate the values from the old table to the new one.
So then I can stop collecting data to the old table and can delete it. Data can be overwritten without issues.
How to do that?

Thanks, Simon